# How to configure ReportViewer so it can be exported CSV in ASP.NET?

Tags: reportviewer

How to configure ReportViewer so it can be exported CSV in ASP.NET (ReportViewer that comes from VisualStudio 2005/2008)?  So it will be apart of current drop downlist? At the moment, it's only for Excel and PDF but not CSV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you run Report Viewer in Local mode, you cannot export to anything other than PDF and Excel.  If you want to be able to export to other formats, you need to run Report Viewer in Server Mode.  The rendering is then done on the SQL server through extensions.

The only way to make Report Viewer export other formats in local mode, is by overriding the render class, and basically write a renderer yourself.  This is quite complicated.

On a side note, you can also enable Word and HTML rendering through Reflection.  Howerver, the rendering of images through this technique is a little sketchy.  I tried doing this, and the images would not render properly.