# Exporting in CSV format using Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, csv, reportviewer

I have to design a web page where a report has to be generated and shown using the Report Viewer control and to be exported to the CSV format also. I have searched a lot but have not found how to export to CSV format. Can that be done?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984617/how-to-configure-reportviewer-so-it-can-be-exported-csv-in-asp-net